# Forcefully setting a field as untouched in angular

Tags: angularjs

In angular js i have a select box which has touched validation defined so it comes red color on wrong selection.

Using this form in a modal. SO once reload the modal with this form that field is  still in red color. How can I forcefully set untouched.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please find this example below,check whether this is useful : 

.directive('untouch', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, modelCtrl) {
            element.on('focus', function() {
                modelCtrl.$setUntouched();
                scope.$apply(); 
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: How I can make sure that ng-disabled on submit button is reset.